# Yocto - Bitbake - Example recipe to add a line in /etc/inittab file

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

I created a recipe "loader_0.1.bb" as examplified below:

```
PACKAGE_ARCH = "all"

SRC_URI = "file://startapp.py"


do_install () {
   install -d ${D}/sbin
   install -m 755 ${WORKDIR}/startapp.py ${D}/sbin/startapp.py
}

FILES_${PN} += "/sbin/startapp.py"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python"
```

But I need to create a new command inside inittab something like

```
MM:12345:respawn:/sbin/startapp.py
```

I found some solutions to add the entire file "inittab", but I can't use this way, because there will be other recipes with other entries in inittab.

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i saw something like that in the meta-swupdate layer: https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate/blob/master/recipes-extended/images/swupdate-image.bb . There is `sed` is used. Maybe you can adjust that to your needs

Comment: Can I ask why you need to do this? Why not let the init system do its job?

Comment: @jku I really want to use the respawn option, do you any ideas to run a executable at boot time and respawn if it crashes.

Comment: @Fl0v0 Thanks, ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND worked perfectly

Comment: @FabioAraujo with systemd this is a basic feature (see [Restart and related options for service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=)). It's true that with sysV this is painful to handle...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a bbappend for the recipe which installs inittab. In my case it was sysvinit-inittab_2.88dsf.bb. In the bbappend file add:

```
do_install_append(){

    echo "MM:12345:respawn:/sbin/startapp.py" >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/inittab

}
```